# Click and toggle between two classes on an array (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, class, button, toggle

I need to make a site where I can add something to a shoppingcart. I do not need to store any data, so just changing a class to 'addedInCart' is enough. This is what I have so far, but it's not working yet. I know all the classnames I got are coming back in an array. I just dont know how to change them if the button is clicked. I tried a lot with the addEventListener and the toggle, but I just started coding, not everything is clear for me yet. I am not alloud to use Jquery, only HTML and Javascript.

This is what I have in Javascript:

```
var buyMe = document.getElementsByClassName("materials-icon");

function shoppingcart() {
        for(let i = 0; i < buyMe.length; i++){
            buyMe[i].classList.toggle("addedInCart");
            buyMe[i].addEventListener("click", toggleClass, false)
        }

    }
```

This is what my button looks like:

```
<button class="material-icons" onclick="shoppingcart()">&#xe8cc;</button>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: First it should be `material-icons` not `materials-icon` as per your HTML element class in JS

Comment: It's a typo. So everything else is fine

Comment: Also, what is the purspose of `buyMe[i].addEventListener("click", toggleClass, false)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to be able to use one handler. Use a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to verify the button as being a button for adding to cart. Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.dataset.cartToggle) {
  //  ^ if element has attribute data-cart-toggle...
    origin.classList.toggle("addedInCart");
    //               ^ ... toggle the class
  }
};
```

```css
.addedInCart {
  color: red;
}

.addedInCart:after {
  content: " (in cart, click to remove)";
}
```

```html
<button class="material-icons" data-cart-toggle="1">buy</button>
<button class="material-icons" data-cart-toggle="1">buy</button>
<button class="material-icons" data-cart-toggle="1">buy</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Thank you for your time, you helped me a lot!